# Is there a way to create a concave physicsBody in SpriteKit?

Tags: sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, concave

I have an object on scene and my hero should not go through it, but it should be able to go inside of it, like a boat into the bay, surrounded by the other element. I tried all kinds of physicsBody having it have body with rectangle, texture, with polygon from path, but to no avail. I was reading somewhere that it is not possible to have a concave physicsBody, but only convex. I really need it to be able to be concave. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Do you mean that a textureBody with alpha does not meet your requirements? I've never tried it but always thought that it let's you define any shape as a body, even concave... The documentation says convex is enforced for polygons physical bodies but nothing for texture with alpha...

Comment: I tried texture based physicsBody yes, the same result... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a concave physics body by adding up a bunch of convex physics bodies into one shape.  Then you can add them as children to an SKNode so that they stick together.  there are some physics editor apps that can help you do this so you arent writing a bunch of coordinates by hand.

Comment: Thanks :) I kind of figured that out, but now this consequent problem is bothering me, I opened a ticket for it, and this should be far more simpler, but apparently isn't:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35692087/why-does-collision-work-properly-for-convex-polygon-based-physicsbody-but-touche

Comment: You can also define it as a separate .sks and included it as needed with a reference node.

Comment: Hey Yunes! :) I don't think I want separate sks included, since I would have dozens of sks inside that sks, which would be an overkill.