# Why does collision work properly for convex polygon based physicsBody but touchesMoved doesn't

Tags: events, sprite-kit, collision, contacts, touchesmoved

I setup an SKSprite (s1) to have physicsBody with polygon from path:

```
s1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:path];
```

and the other one (s2) has physicsBody generated from its surrounding rectangle:

```
s2.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:e.size];
```

and the collisions of the two sprites are fine, they only happen when the actual pixels from the s1's polygon path and surrounding rectangle from the s2 collide (and not the surrounding rectangles from each of the sprites). This is fine. But the touchesMoved in the s1 - which has polygon based body - occurs when its surrounding rectangle is touched - even though it has the polygon based physicsBody (see above code for setting the physicsBody of s1). How can I solve this problem and have this event only fire when it should, which is when actual pixels (defined by the polygon based physicsBody) are touched?

I tried detecting the body at point:

```
SKPhysicsBody * draggedOverBody = [self.physicsWorld bodyAtPoint:location];

draggedOverNode = draggedOverBody.node;
```

and also it only detects the bounding rectangle instead of the polkygon physicsBody. Very frustrating.

Comment: This is confusing, are you saying when you call a touch move event, you are not touching the polygon, but it moves anyway?

Comment: It looks like you don't know what touchesMoved refers to. It doesn't move anything on the spritekit, it just refers to the event analog to mouse drag. And this is when finger moves on the screen.

Comment: I know what touch move does, I dont understand how you are using it

Comment: when I say "you call", I mean you drag your finger, physically firing off the event

Comment: I will rename the title of the question. But if you read again through the description, I'm sure you will see my problem. touchesMoved sees the sprite's physicsBody always as a rectangle based, instead of polygon based, like collision and contact do. Both of those see sprites as polygon based and fire off accordingly.

Comment: oh, ok now that makes sense, you are saying when you touch outside of a polygon it treats it as a rectangle and is registering,  yes touch based code does not go off of your physics body, it goes off of the frame of the SKNode.  You need to add an additional check inside of your touch move code to determing if you are indeed inside of it

Comment: So do you know how can I register touchesMoved to only trigger when that sprite is touched inside its polygon - defined in physicsBody as polygon?

Comment: I believe SKShapeNodes has this auto built in, but you are using an SKSpriteNode,  so you can cheat and have an SKShapeNode that has a child of SKSpriteNode, or you can to a check if the point is inside the physics body

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104888/discussion-between-vladimir-despotovic-and-knight0fdragon).