# Physics on the edge of a UIBezierPath Arc

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am struggling to create physics for an arc. Drawing this arc I only need to apply physics to the white line shown. Drawn with this code.

[image: my arc]

```
let position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
let width = CGFloat(5)
let inner = 300/2-width
let outer = 300/2+width
let start = 3*CGFloat.pi/2-offset
let end = 3*CGFloat.pi/2+offset

let arc = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: position, radius: inner, startAngle: start, endAngle: end, clockwise: true)

let shape = SKShapeNode(path: arc.cgPath)
shape.strokeColor = SKColor.white
shape.lineWidth = 2
shape.fillColor = SKColor.blue
shape.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFrom: arc.cgPath)
shape.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

self.addChild(shape)
```

Naturally physics is applied to the entire shape. Adding in this code nets me something prettier

[image: fancier arc]

```
arc.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: outer * cos(end), y: outer * sin(end)))
arc.addArc(withCenter: position, radius: outer, startAngle: end, endAngle: start, clockwise: false)
```

But the same physics still apply as they did in the first one.

How do I create an arc that has proper physics for the second arc?

**EDIT:**

Showing physics and using clear color also including the floating ball.

[image]

Comment: Did you turn on showPhysics to see if your body is correct?

Comment: Yes the body even shows it is where it says it is. It's like the shadow is still there

Comment: I even attempted to create an arc utilizing `addLine` over 10 points and I still have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my problem. This is an issue with the physics generator itself. It will only create convex polygons not concave. So I utilized what is seen in [Is there a way to create a concave physicsBody in SpriteKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35690531/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-concave-physicsbody-in-spritekit).

Adding a loop in my code to create rectangles of the arc netted me something I can work with

[image]

```
let points = 8 //number of rectangles/2
var q = CGFloat(start)
var bodies = [SKPhysicsBody]()
for i in 1...(points*2)
{
    let parc = UIBezierPath()
    parc.move(to: CGPoint(x: inner * cos(q), y: inner * sin(q)))
    parc.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: outer * cos(q), y: outer * sin(q)))
    q += (offset/CGFloat(points))
    parc.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: outer * cos(q), y: outer * sin(q)))
    parc.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: inner * cos(q), y: inner * sin(q)))
    parc.close()
    bodies.append(SKPhysicsBody(polygonFrom: parc.cgPath))
}

//adjusting code to allow a physics body from multiple physics body instead of one
//shape.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFrom: arc.cgPath)
shape.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(bodies: bodies)
```